# Programmatically opening a window in Swift 3 MacOS

Tags: macos, swift3, segue, viewcontroller

I want to open a window programmatically because I need to send a variable to the window as it is opening. MacOS.

I have created a new window controller and a new view controller. Both are called from ViewController.

```
@IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let SB = NSStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let NVC = SB.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as! NewViewController
    let NWC = SB.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "NewWindowController") as! NSWindowController

    NVC.inputString = outputString
    NWC.showWindow(self)
}
```

The new window never opens.
NewViewController loads but no data is passed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { // NewViewController
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    print(inputString)
    print("end")
}
```

Rather than open a window programmatically, I used the IB to generate a segue which then passed the data. The new controller was opened as "show". I assigned a name to the segue in the IB. Of course, that required overriding the prepare function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "TestSegue") {
        let NVC:NewViewController = segue.destinationController as! NewViewController
        
        NVC.name = "test"
    }
}
```

The passed data was then accessed in NewViewController's viewDidLoad.

The code is, admittedly, simple, but it seems to work.

Comment: What's the question? If the problem is solved, delete the question or answer it in the Answer field.

Answer (score -1):

Two view controllers: ViewController.swift and NewViewController.swift.

Define a segue in ViewController.swift

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "TestSegue") {
        let NVC:NewViewController = segue.destinationController as! NewViewController
        
        NVC.name = "test"
    }
}
```

In NewViewController.swift, define a variable to receive a value passed from ViewController.swift, and access that variable in NewViewController.swift's viewDidLoad function.